# Exam answer confirmation - Amortized time

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

The following method op belongs to a class with two private integer-valued instance variables, n
and counter, both of which are initialised to the value zero in the constructor, and subsequently only
modified by method op.

```
public void op()
{
    if(counter<100)
    {
        op1(); //method with O(1) time complexity
        counter++;
    }else {
        op2(); //method with O(n^2) time complexity
        counter = 0;
    }
    n++;
}
```

Assuming that method op1 has time complexity O(1) , and method op2 has time complexity O(n^2), which of the following best represents the amortized time complexity of method op?

A) O(n)

B) O(n log n)

C) O(1)

**D) O(n^2)**

E) O(n3)

where the answer to the exam was D. I think it should have been C as from my understanding of amortized time, you count what will occur *most* of the time. In this situation, the worst case is O(n^2), however most of the time the algorithm will run in O(1). Why is it O(n^2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When talking about amortized runtime, you can **not** count what will occur *most* of the time. 
To start, how do you even define *most of the time*?
The amortized runtime of an operation can be seen as the average runtime of the operation.

### Now to your problem:

For simplicity, I will assume that you wrote `if (counter < 99)` instead of `if (counter < 100)`. This way, the operation repeats itself after 100 cycles instead of after 101 cycles.

When writing `O(...)`, in the following, I will actually mean `Θ(...)`, because otherwise the answer to your question would be trivial, as everything which is `O(1)` is also `O(n^2)`.

After calling `op()` 100 times, the total run time would be `99 + 100^2`.
After calling `op()` 200 times, the total run time would be `2 * 99 + 100^2 + 200^2`.
Now let's just forget about those `99` or `2 * 99`, as they are dominated by the `n^2` values.
So after calling `op()` `n` times, the total run time would be something like `100^2 + 200^2 + ... + n^2` (for simplicity, let's assume that `n` is divisible by `100`).

Now I will show that this is in `O(n^3)`.

```
Let k = n/100

100^2 + 200^2 + ... + n^2
= 100^2 * (1^2 + 2^2 + ... + k^2)
=(*) O(100^2 * k * k^2)
= O(k^3)
= O(n^3)

(*): sum from 1 to k of i^2 is k (k+1) (2k+1) / 6 = O(k^3)
```

So finally, the average runtime of `op()` is `O(n^3 / n) = O(n^2)`. Therefore, the amortized runtime of `op()` is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Wow, you did not only explain but even *prove* your answer.